# How to sort one observable collection with another observable collection in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have one string observable collection called "A" containing some values. Another string observable collection called "B" containing some values.

"A" has 13 values and "B" has 5 values.
"A" contains "B" values but in a different order. I want "B" values in "A" get first priority in a combobox.

So what I have to do.. write some linq query.
Please give some ideas.

Comment: What collection of these two is bound to combobox? It is not clear, what do you mean under 'get first priority'.

Comment: @Dennis i hve two combobox one is from location and other is to location.to location observable collection items contains from location items.i want from location items in top of to location observable collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have my IDE handy but something like this should do it.

This one assumes the same instances exist in the two collections.

```
var sortedA = observableA.OrderBy(item=>observableB.Contains(item) ? 0 : 1);
```

If they are not the same instances and you wanted to compare a property such as `name` you could also do.

```
var sortedA = observableA.OrderBy(item=>observableB.Any(item2 => item2.Name == item.Name) ? 0 : 1);
```

Comment: hi..@richard..i am not that much experience in linq.so according to first condition if item present it return "0" else "1".what is this 0 and 1.whether it is true or false something..can u explaing little bit..?advance thanks

Comment: It is sorting by the 1 or the 0 - if it is higher priority then its sort order is 0 (putting it at the top) if it is lower priority (not in the 2nd collection) then its sort index is 1 and appears after the ones with a 0 sort index. :)

Comment: ..so i can give some other value like 2,3 instead of 0,1..or we should give 0 and 1..?

Comment: You can give it any value you like depending on what you want it to do, in this instance you just wanted it sorted depending on if it exists in the other collection, but you can sort on whatever you want..

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13".Split(',').ToList();
var b = "7,8,9,10,11".Split(',').ToList();

var c = a.OrderByDescending(x => b.IndexOf(x));
```